# C++ script can't retrieve variable from AHK

Tags: c++, autohotkey

I'm trying to make a C++ script that runs an AHK thread and retrieves a variable from it. It manages to run the AHK script without a problem but it doesn't seem to return anything.

```
typedef UINT (*pahkdll)(LPTSTR script,LPTSTR p1,LPTSTR p2);
typedef BOOL (*pahkReady)(void);

HINSTANCE handle;
pahkdll ahkdll;

pahkReady ahkReady;


void debugAHK(){
   while (!ahkReady()){
      Sleep(10);
   }
}

bool init(){
    handle = LoadLibrary("AutoHotkey.dll");
    if (!handle){ std::cout << "Could not load dynamic library!\n"; return 0;}

    ahkdll = (pahkdll)GetProcAddress(handle, "ahkdll");
    ahkReady = (pahkReady)GetProcAddress(handle, "ahkReady");

    ahkdll("","","");

    debugAHK();

   return 1;
}

void check(){
    ahkdll("ahk.ahk", "", "");
    debugAHK();
    typedef wchar_t* (*AhkGetVar)(wchar_t *, UINT);
    AhkGetVar l_hAutoHotKeyGetVar = (AhkGetVar)GetProcAddress(handle, "ahkgetvar");
    wchar_t* wcha = l_hAutoHotKeyGetVar(L"MyVar", 0); // 0 : content, 1 : pointer

    std::wstring wcha(l_sRes);
    std::cout << std::string(w.begin(), w.end());

}
```

When I attempt to return the content it doesn't return anything. When I attempt to return a pointer it just returns a seemingly random sequence of numbers with a .txt suffix or some other random string.
The AHK script is simply:

```
#Persistent
#NoTrayIcon
MyVar := "test"
```